# Laravel 5.7 verify email localization

Tags: php, laravel, internationalization, email-verification

Laravel provides an ability to use different language by using app.config + `lang` folder. However, I don't see any reference in the docs on how to translate base email.

I've enabled email verification, however email is sent using English what confuses my users. How do I translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#defining-translation-strings, simply add a json file to lang folder, named with the desired language, using the strings that you want translate as keys of json object:

[image: json object in lang folder]

Comment: This is not about emails. It works not as a "translation" but as a key=>value to use somewhere via `__(message.hello)`. Thus it's not an answer to my question.