# How to translate Laravel 5.7 Email Verification?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I translate the Laravel Email Verification?

> Some packages may ship with their own language files. Instead of changing the package's core files to tweak these lines, you may override them by placing files in the resources/lang/vendor/{package}/{locale} directory. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#overriding-package-language-files

And if we check the localization documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys

And the VerifyEmail class:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php#L44

Then we have to create this file resources/lang/vendor/Auth/de.json with this content:

```
{
   "Verify Email Address": "Email Adresse bestätigen"
}
```

But this does not work. My Laravel version is 5.7.15. Do not confuse with [Laravel 5.7 verify email localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557143/laravel-5-7-verify-email-localization), this is for the view, not email. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried just `resources/lang/de.json` instead? The `vendor` subdirectory is just for third-party modules I believe, not core Laravel packages.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I answered almost the same question a few weeks back ^^^

Comment: Do you know how to translate the footer? If you’re having trouble clicking the "Verify Email Address" button, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser. I published the template with:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

How can I translate this with parameters within de.json?


`@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
        'actionURL' => $actionUrl,
    ]
)`

Comment: Check my answer linked above, I just updated it. I don't know why they felt like they needed two different methods for internationalization, but you do that in a PHP file.